# Multiple IPs to different domains Apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

I have managed to do this before without any issues, now Im stuck.

I have the following problem: I have two IPs connected to my Ubuntu VPS. 111.111.11.111 and 222.222.22.222. 111.111.11.111 is the "default" IP for the server. 222.222.22.222 is the secondary IP which I try to add my site example.com to. The strange thing is when I try to browse or ping my example.com site it times out, both on domain and IP, 100% packet loss.

When I than browse 111.111.11.111 I reach my site example.com (content shows up) which should show up only on 222.222.22.222. How come this happen, what have I missed?

System
Ubuntu18.04
Apache2.4.29

- Site 000-default disabled.
- All website files on server are in /var/www/example.com/public_html/ (also this is where - if I browse - 111.111.11.111 reach downs to)

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 the-server-name
222.222.22.222 example.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Edit 1: 
First looking in /etc/network/interfaces got me this:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

So when going to /etc/netplan there is a linked .yaml file which I added the 222.222.22.222 IP in, it now look this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens192:
            match:
                macaddress: '02:01:84:66:71:01'
            set-name: ens192
            gateway4: 111.111.11.111
            gateway6: '2a02:0750:0009:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001'
            addresses:
                - 111.111.11.111/23
                - '2a02:750:9::3c9/64'
                - 222.222.22.222/23
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                    - 33.33.3.300
                    - 33.33.3.301
                    - '2a02:751:aaaa::1'
                    - '2a02:751:aaaa::2'
```

After doing this I am able to ping and browse 222.222.22.222. I think I will solve the rest. Thank you for the help!

Edit 2:
I thought I would solve the rest, but struggling here as well. I can reach the site through the IP as stated but not by the domain name. Although the Apache access.log registers every visitors which tries to reach the site.

Why am I getting "Connection refused"?

netstat -lntp | grep ':80'

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      724/apache2
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue Nov 20 21:30:12.537727 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7538] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 20 21:30:12.627503 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7720] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 20 21:30:12.627574 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7720] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Nov 20 21:31:01.605035 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 7746] [client 58.182.34.135:35914] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
[Tue Nov 20 21:34:15.751251 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7720] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 20 21:34:15.840563 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7883] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 20 21:34:15.840667 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7883] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Nov 20 21:38:03.325023 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7883] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 20 21:38:15.988516 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 724] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 20 21:38:16.003974 2018] [core:notice] [pid 724] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: If you want `222.222.22.222:80`, your config file shouldn't say `*:80`.

Comment: I've also tried that as well with the same result.

Comment: If you cannot ping your website it is a good sign that something is going on network layer3. You should check how you **default gateway** is configures on the VPS, having two public IPs on the machine is always tricky and needs to be configured properly. Do you even receive any traffic on the second interface? You can sniff the packages that interface gets by running 

`sudo tcpdump -i eth1 icmp` - gets ICMP packets on the interface eth1
`sudo tcpdump -i eth1 port 80` - gets packets received on port 80 on eth1

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `<VirtualHost *:80>` to achieve this. As documented in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html "the server must have a different IP address/port combination for each IP-based virtual host". In that documentation are also examples how to get it right.